# Cannot add new queue in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

Hi guys i cannot add new queue in sidekiq, there are several command like `bundle exec sidekiq -q queue_name` or via rails console `Sidekiq::Queue.new("queue_name")` those two commands still cannot create new queue both in redis. Here is the sidekiq web UI [sidekiq web ui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDFMa.png) , there is no such queue `queue_name` in those web ui, it does means that `queue_name` doesn't created right ?

I'm really new into sidekiq, anyone can help me which steps that i missed ?, note: i'm not using file configuration to create new queue sidekiq but just commands. Thanks guys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to push a job into the queue for it to be created.